# Core Data to Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, core-data, frameworks

I want to create a cocoa touch framework that is fetching data from an Api and stores it on a local database. Is it possible to add core data in a cocoa touch framework ?

Comment: You need to do a modicum of research yourself. Short answer: why not?

Comment: Yes, should be fine.

Answer (score -3):

It's no problem to use `Core Data` in `Cocoa Touch Framework`. I've done it myself in plenty of apps.

The [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1) should get you started.

Comment: This tutorial is explaining how to use core data in an ios project. Creating a framework is a difference proccess

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realized that the tutorial doesn't mention frameworks. I removed the link from my answer.